# Issues with Skin Clusters in Clara.io and threejs

Tags: three.js, fbx

I am seeing strange scaling issues for FBX and DAE files that are imported into Clara.io and Threejs which use Skin Cluster nodes.

Here is an example of a model that is broken. Note that the hose of the vacuum used a Skin Cluster node.

What the FBX file should look like (Screen shot take in Unity):
[image]

FBX File in Clara.io:
[image]

As you can see, the hose and its children are much larger scale than they should be.